# spawn expect in windows

Tags: windows, tcl, expect

Hi I am newbee to expect in tcl script

I want to ssh to the particular router and send some command like date using tcl
I have developed the tcl script in windows:

```
#!/bin/sh
# \
exec C:/Tcl/bin/tclsh86/ "$0" ${1+"$@"}
package require Expect

spawn ssh "user\@x.x.x.x"
expect "*word:"
send "password\r";
expect "*>"
send "date\r";
```

and when I am executing the script, I am getting below error:
`Child process exited abnormally.`

Could anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong and how to make it go correct?

Comment: This should help you, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637915/tcl-expect-fails-spawning-ssh-to-server-but-ssh-from-command-line-works

Comment: Sorry Vardd. The link is for linux based but i am using in windows :(